# Restrict white space on Jquery Datables Editor Modal Popup input field

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to restrict white space in an input field on the Jquery Datable Editor pop up modal.

Element

```
<input id="DTE_Field_re-re_netipaddress" type="text">
```

My Attempt

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input#DTE_Field_remoteinstalltickets-remoteinstallticket_netipaddress").on({
  keydown: function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32)
      return false;
  },
  change: function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    alert("did this fire?");
  }
}); 
});
```

The alert box doesn't fire and it doesnt restrict white space.

How do i access the Jquery Datable Editor pop up elements?

Comment: You can do this with CSS

Comment: is this only visibility or will it actually remove the white space if I save the field to a database?